# Catch NetworkManager Exceptions in Codename One

Tags: exception, codenameone

How can I catch IOException that occurs when I trying to use addToQueue method of NetworkManager class with no Internet connection?

> java.io.IOException: Unreachable  at
>   com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.connect(JavaSEPort.java:5120)    at
>   com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.connect(JavaSEPort.java:5152)    at
>   com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:290)
>     at
>   com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:261)
>     at
>   com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either override the error methods in `ConnectionRequest` or for a global solution add an error listener to the `NetworkManager` and consume the events.

Comment: performOperation function of ConnectionRequest can't be override.

Comment: Well. I can override handleException function )

Comment: handleException or handleIOException were the methods I was referring to.